# 'Parallelized pipeline' program design in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, pipeline

Not sure if I'm phrasing this properly, if I'm over complicating things, or if this is even an appropriate place to ask such a broad question, but I'm trying to write a command-line application that performs the following operations:

1. Scrapes forum comments from a number of various websites.
2. Iterates over each forum comment and parses out strings matching a particular pattern.
3. For each string that hasn't been processed before, perform a conditional check and process it. If the check yields true, terminate execution gracefully. (Note: the termination is the goal; otherwise the program will otherwise continue to run indefinitely.)

I've already written a simple program to do this, but I'd like to streamline things a bit. (The way I had previously written it was very procedural.) I'd like to design the application such that when a forum comment is scraped, it is immediately passed off to code that parses substrings from it. The original forum scraping code would then return to scraping, while a separate process(?) or thread(?) handles the strings, etc. I almost conceptualize things working like a pipeline, such that after each stage of processing the resulting data is passed to the next stage and queued up. This, of course, could be complete overkill; however,  time is a relatively important factor here, hence why I'd like to be able to continue scraping the forum sites while strings are processed in parallel.

The problem is that I've mostly developed simpler, non-multithreaded / multi-process applications, so I'm not sure how to go about this. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is probably not a bad question, but more appropriate at the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site. I'd suggest posting the code as well.

Comment: The book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net) teaches concurrency in Java using web crawling as an example. Because your question is pretty broad, I suggest that you look into the book and come back with a narrowed question.